# A question about the 2nd order DE $y^2 y'' = -(y')^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the 2nd order DE

$$y^2 y'' = -(y')^3$$

We have

$$(\frac{y}{y'})^2 \frac{y''}{y'} = -1$$

and I let $p = \frac{y}{y'}$, so I get

$$p' = \frac{(y')^2 - y y''}{(y')^2} = 1 - p \frac{y''}{y'}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{y''}{y'} = \frac{p'-1}{-p}$$

So we have

$$p^2 \frac{p'-1}{-p} = -1$$

$$\Rightarrow p' = \frac{dp}{dx} = 1 + \frac{1}{p} = \frac{p+1}{p}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{p}{p+1}dp = 1dx$$

$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{p}{p+1}dp = \int 1dx$$

$$\Rightarrow p - \ln(1+p) = x + C$$

But if we plug $p = \frac{y}{y'}$ into the solution we get just now, it will be even harder to solve it.

So I am wondering whether there is a better way to do it. Can someone give some hint on it or tell me any other ways to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly separate the factors so that both sides are integrable

$$
\frac{y''}{y'^2}+\frac{y'}{y^2}=0\implies \frac1{y'}+\frac1y=C
$$
which now is again separable as a first-order equation.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From

$$
p + 1 - \ln(p + 1) = x + C + 1\Rightarrow p = \frac{y}{y'}=-\left(W\left(-e^{-(x+C+1)}\right)+1\right)
$$

and then

$$
y = c_1 W\left(-e^{-(x+C+1)}\right)
$$

where $W$ is the Lambert function.

Comment: Thanks! But I am still taking undergrad level ODE class and haven't learnt Lambert function yet. So I am wondering whether there are other ways to do this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch variables, the equation becomes
$$-\frac{x''}{[x']^3}\,y^2=-\frac{1}{[x']^3}$$ Assuming $x'\neq 0$,
$$x''\,y^2-1=0$$ which is very simple

$$x=c_1+c_2\,y-\log(y)$$

Now, if you want to inverse it, you need to use Lambert function.

Answer (score 1):

HINT…set $$y’’=y’\frac{dy’}{dy}$$

Then you have either $y’=0$ or a separable variable DE you can solve.